# How to fix error when using ssh github keys on ubuntu?

Tags: git, github, ssh

The problem is I have ssh keys already working on my local disk but, when I am going to use Ubuntu, it doesn't let me use the keys like shown in this images:

This is my local disk ssh keys:

[image: local disk ssh keys]

This is the carpet ssh but on Ubuntu folder:

[image: carpet ssh but on Ubuntu folder]

When I am going to request a git clone with ssh it doesn't work:

[image: Ubuntu failed SSH]

Comment: Don't use images where cut-and-paste text will serve (use the `ls` command in your Ubuntu terminal window to show what's in your .ssh directory, and cut-and-paste the result). In any case the problem is clear: you don't have any ssh keys set up in your Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to:

- regenerate a new set of SSH key pair on your Ubuntu session, instead of reusing existing keys: that way, you can better identify which account is using/accessing your GitHub data.
- register the new SSH public key on your GitHub account

In your Ubuntu session:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -P ""
```